# Using Angular to load local JSON file

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

> This is my method to call a local JSON file. However, the JSON can be
>   seen in the browser console but nothing is being seen in the HTML
>   page, can anyone see anything I am missing in my code. Thanks

```
  loadUser(){

  this.http.get('assets/json/collection.json')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data.results;
    console.log(data.results);
  });
}


    <div *ngFor="let result of results">   
        <p>{{results.title}}</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Guessing that your loadUser() function is part of your component class, you probable have to call "data" in your template, as you assign *data.results* to *this.data*

```
<div *ngFor="let result of data">   
    <p>{{result.title}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: cannot find a differ supporting object [object Object] is the error i get when i change it to <div *ngFor="let result of data"> what ive read is that its how the json is coming back as an object

Comment: Can you paste the console.log result please?

Comment: loadUser(){
  
  this.http.get('assets/json/collection.json')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data.results;
    console.log(data.results);
  });
}

 ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad HomePage');
     this.loadUser();
  }

Comment: @scipper 's answer is right, I think. When is `ionViewDidLoad()` called? I think you should call `this.loadUser()` in `ngOnInit()`

Comment: I'm getting the error "Cannot find a differ supporting object [ object Object]" of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding o iterables such as arrays.          When I change to match scipper's suggestion?

Comment: are you sure `data.results` is correct? what's it say in your json file?

Comment: {
    
    "results": {
        "id": 21,
        "title": "Arsenal Test Collection",
        "identifier": null,
        "colour_bg": "#bd2c2c",
        "colour_btn": "#a11212",
        "colour_content_bg": "#ffffff",
        "logo_dashboard": "collection/21/SVwnz6tjluX81dIRNXjZo7issYUWyOVyD3LJFykm.png",
        "logo_page": "collection/21/txgkqlkPA45mHSYtqZ5rFa4wLfHNUfXESE0xyhwp.png",   thats the top part of my JSON

Comment: Maybe I figured out the problem: Are you trying to iterate over all properties of the user object? As the functions "loadUser" suggests, it always return an object (1 user), and not an array of users. So, *ngFor is probably the wrong approach. If you know the properties you want to echo, just call them directly: <div><p>{{ data.title }}</p></div> (guessing the you mapped this.data = data.results)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make it so `this.data` is an Array of type result. So you would have to set up a model called Result. Also if your JSON has more than one result, you should make something like this:

**collection.json**

```
{
  "results":[ 
       {
         "id": 20,
         "title": "asdasd",
         "identifier": null,
         "colour_bg": "#bd2c2c",
         "colour_btn": "#a11212",
         "colour_content_bg": "#ffffff", 
         "logo_dashboard": "collection/21/SVwnz6tjluX81dIRNXjZo7issYUWyOVyD3LJFykm.png"‌​,
         "logo_page": "collection/21/txgkqlkPA45mHSYtqZ5rFa4wLfHNUfXESE0xyhwp.png"‌​
       },
       {
         "id": 21,
         "title": "Arsenal Test Collection",
         "identifier": null,
         "colour_bg": "#bd2c2c",
         "colour_btn": "#a11212",
         "colour_content_bg": "#ffffff", 
         "logo_dashboard": "collection/21/SVwnz6tjluX81dIRNXjZo7issYUWyOVyD3LJFykm.png"‌​,
         "logo_page": "collection/21/txgkqlkPA45mHSYtqZ5rFa4wLfHNUfXESE0xyhwp.png"‌​
       }
    ]
 }
```

**result.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Result{

   id: number; 
   title: String;
   identifier: String; 
   colour_bg: String;
   colour_btn: String; 
   colour_content_bg: String; 
   logo_dashboard: String;
   logo_page: String;

   constructor(){
   }

}
```

Then in your Page

**page.ts**

```
import { Result } from 'path/to/your/model/folder/result/
data: Array<Result> = [];

loadUser(){
   this.http.get('assets/json/collection.json')
   .map(res => res.json())
   .subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data.results;
      console.log(data.results);
   });
}
```

---

**EDIT**

You could also set up each Result object inside the subscribe and then push them into a final array. 
**IMPORTANT:** Call loadUsers inside ionViewWillEnter(), so it runs every time you enter the page.

```
loadUsers()  {
    let results = [];
    var i;
    this.http.get('assets/json/collection.json')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      for(i=0; i< data.results.length;i++) {
          let result = new Result();
          // add each attr to the result object
          // i.e.
          result.id = data.results[i].id
          //push the object to the final array
          results.push(result)
        }
      })
      this.data = results;
    }
```

Comment: Will the HTMl output like so <div *ngFor="let item of results">
        <p>{{item.id}}</p>
    </div>

Comment: The JSON is still showing in the browser but not in the HTML page?

Comment: Did you add the array to the json?

Comment: The other thing you can do is manually set each object inside the subscribe and push them to an array

Comment: Sorry how do you mean?

Comment: I have something like this for an app i'm building.

Comment: I'll make another answer

Comment: Chester that is great thanks, managed to get it working. I hope your app is going good :D